# How to delete selected rows of an html table based on a checkbox column using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, html-table

I have made a simple html table with a column of checkboxes, as well as some other columns. Above that, is a delete button that will call a service function I have already made, but I want it to delete every checked box that the column has. How would I send my delete function an array of checked "projects"?

Below is the delete button code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <button class="btn pull-right btn-danger button-project-request form-group" value="Submit" ng-click=deleteCheckedProjects()>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Below is the table code:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="project"/></td>
            <td ng-click=editRequestModule(project)>{{project.project.projNm}}</td>
            <td>{{convertMilliseconds(project.project.strtDt)}}</td>
            <td>{{convertMilliseconds(project.project.endDt)}}</td>
            <td>{{project.project.statusId.staDescription}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Any advice on how to go about this? Maybe in Javascript, establish a two way bounded array that holds all the checked boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I think the *simplest* implementation would be to replace your checkboxes with individual delete buttons:

```
<tr ng-repeat="proj in projects">
    <td><button ng-click="remove(proj)">delete</button><td>
    <td>{{proj.name}}</td>
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

Where `remove` is something to the effect of:

```
$scope.remove = function(proj){
    $scope.projects.splice($scope.projects.indexOf(proj), 1);
}
```

---

If you're set on checkboxes, you can include some sort of "staged for delete" flag in your project model:

```
<tr ng-repeat="proj in projects">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="proj.will_delete"></td>
    <td>{{proj.name}}</td>
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
<button ng-click="remove_staged()">delete</button>
```

Where `remove_staged` is something like:

```
$scope.remove_staged = function(){
    $scope.projects = $scope.projects.filter(proj=> !proj.will_delete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'project-checkbox' class to each checkbox, then use

```
var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName('project-checkbox');
```

to get every checkbox.
From there you can create an empty array, loop through the `checkboxes` array and check if it has been checked before adding it to the new array.

```
var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassname('project-checkbox');
var checkedProjects=[];
for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
  if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
    checkedProjects.append(checkboxes[i]);  
  }
}
```

Now `checkedProjects` has every checked checkbox, and you can access the project it is contained in via `checkedProjects[i].parentNode`

A slightly more efficient way to do it would be to change the class name whenever it is checked or unchecked, then use `document.getElementsByClassName()` to get the checked class name only.

Comment: Finding all checked checkboxes can be done in a line, see my answer

Comment: I have to use parentNode.parentNode, and that gets me the html table code back. I'm not sure how to pull project out of this

Comment: Hmm I am not sure exactly what you mean by table code. But it sounds like that is the table containing the project? If so, you can do `checkedProjects[i].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(checkedProjects[i].parentNode)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it with JS (JQuery)

Add to every checkbox you want to track the class `.myCheckboxClass`

```js
var deleteCheckedProjects = function() {

    // this will return all checked checkboxes with class .myCheckboxClass
    var checked = $('.myCheckboxClass:checkbox:checked') 
  
    // you can delete the input in the DOM
    for (i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
    
       checked[i].remove();
    
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="myCheckboxClass" type="checkbox" name="first">Hello Sir!<br>
<input class="myCheckboxClass" type="checkbox" name="first">I am not here</input><br>

<br>

<button onclick="deleteCheckedProjects()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Alternatively you can just return the array:

```
var deleteCheckedProjects = function() {

  // this will return all checked checkboxes with class .myCheckboxClass
  return $('.myCheckboxClass:checkbox:checked') 

}
```

Comment: Manipulating the DOM this way will desyncronize the view and the model of application: clicking "delete" will remove the project from the view, but the model remains untouched. You'll notice OP mentioned this is an angularjs project

Comment: Ok maybe I should remove `checked[i].remove()` but OP asked "How would I **send my delete function an array of checked 'projects'**?"